# ¿Cómo puedo definir el formato del valor que recibo de un datetimepicker en c#?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Verán yo tengo un datetimepicker y quiero que su valor quede en el formato: "yyyy/MM/dd". Ya lo modifiqué desde la forma:

[image: Forma de Prueba]

Pero por alguna razón me coloca la fecha en un formato distinto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que me regrese el valor en el formato que quiero. Este es mi código y utilizo una pila para guardar los valores.

```
 foreach (Control x in forma.Controls)
            {
       else if (x is DateTimePicker) {
                         // string prueba;
                                DateTimePicker auxDate = x as DateTimePicker;
                         // prueba = Convert.ToDateTime(auxDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")).ToString();
                                pila.Push(Convert.ToDateTime(auxDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")));
                                //posicion++;
                            }
                       
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a establecer la propiedad CustomFormat:

```
// Establecemos el Custom format
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
// Le decimos que use nuestro formato propio
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes jugar con los formatos que permite las variables tipo DateTime es decir: **datetimepicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")** como lo haces aqui auxDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), veras que imprime como cadena en el formato que deseas